# HTTP/S Site Maps

Tags: https, sitemap

I am in the process of transitioning a fairly sizable website to https. However, I have found different information regarding site maps.

Should I switch my site map to https BEFORE I launch https?

Should I switch my site may to https AFTER I launch https?

Should I have two site maps (one with http protocols and the other with https)?

I am very concerned with a possible hit to SEO after https goes live so any and all suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: You should create two separate sitemaps -- one for HTTP, and one for HTTPS. See [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55657).

Comment: Thank you so much this is very helpful!